# Couldn't find the expected Java Key Stores (JKS) files! They are mandatory when encryption via TLS is enabled

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, jks

I'm trying to get bitnami kafka, helm version, working with TLS certificates but am getting the above error in the log file of
my kafka pod, mykafka-0, when its status becomes ERROR. Here is what I do:

1. To generate the truststore.jks and keystore.jks, I use a script, kafka-generate-ssl.sh, given in "Enable TLS"
   (https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/kafka/administration/enable-tls/).
2. To create a secret containing the truststore and keystore, I execute the command given on the above mentioned web page, i.e.

```
kb create secret generic kafka-tls \
  --from-file=./truststore/kafka.truststore.jks \
  --from-file=./keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
```

NOTE: I only have 1 broker, so I only have 1 kafka.keystore.jks

3. I look at the secret using this command: `kubectl describe secret kafka-tls`. And here is what is output:

```
Name:         kafka-tls
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
kafka.keystore.jks:    5069 bytes
kafka.truststore.jks:  1306 bytes
```

4. I start kakfa with the following command:

```
helm install mykafka ./kafka  \
  --set auth.interBrokerProtocol=tls \
  --set auth.tls.type=jks \
  --set auth.tls.existingSecret=kafka-tls \
  --set auth.tls.password=mypassword
```

NOTE; the '--set' are those given on the above mentioned web page.

5. Maybe 5 minutes later, I check the status of my pods with this command `kubectl get pods`. Here is the output:

```
kafka-64fb77b646-mm4kd       0/1     Pending                 0          7m34s
mykafka-0                    0/1     ERROR                   4          7m34s
mykafka-zookeeper-0          1/1     Running                 0          7m34s
zookeeper-6f99fcbbb6-sd4vk   0/1     Pending                 0          7m34s
```

6. I looked at the log file for the pod using this command: `kubectl logs mykafka-0`. Here is the output:

```
Couldn't find the expected Java Key Stores (JKS) files! They are mandatory when encryption via TLS is enabled
```

By the way, my kubenetes cluster is on azure.

Answer (score 1):

`Rename your keystores to "kafka-X.keystore.jks" where X is the ID of each Kafka broker.`

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/8ebbf6e0af566e05e794562d9a4d1e4f73ce1502/bitnami/kafka/values.yaml#L307

Answer (score 0):

Before you create your secret, rename the kakfa.keystore.jks file to kakfa-0.keystore.jks. This should get you past the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look to the documentation [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/kafka/administration/enable-tls/#use-jks-format). The secret's name needs the ID of the broker.